# Echo php with echoed html php

Tags: php, html

I currently have a php which echo my html template.

However in that HTML template there is another echo which calls from another php script.

Just wondering how do I do that? Because once I echo my html template the other it doesn't seems to echo my content from the other php script.

HTML TEMPLATE

```
<php? $html = '<span>name:<?php echo $name; ?></span><span>email:<?php echo $email; ?></span>' ?>
```

CONTACT TEMPLATE

```
<php? $name = "hello world"; $email = "hello@world.com"; ?>
```

Comment: Is this typo error `<php?`

Comment: PHP isn't executed recursively. `<?php ... ?>` code inside strings is not executed.

Comment: @Nawin Maybe it's part of the template system?

Comment: Thank you for you respond. Is there a way that I can make the string executed within then?

Comment: Switch to a proper template system like Twig(https://twig.sensiolabs.org/), it's easy to do and more secure than a role your own.

Comment: You should concat them instead of printing them. check the reply that is provided by dsb.

Comment: @Hossein Yes. I tried concat method, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

I can see what you're trying to do, and it's a simple error. You can't escape php like that whilst inside setting a variable.

Also, I must add that you are declaring php incorrectly.

This is preferred

```
<?php
```

not

```
<php?
```

So make sure for your contact template you use the correct tag.

Also to include a file you have to call it/require it.

Back to the original question - Here is your method

```
<php? $html = '<span>name:<?php echo $name; ?></span><span>email:<?php echo $email; ?></span>' ?>
```

Here is the correct method

```
<?php 
 require('contact.php');
 $html = '<span>name:'.$name.'</span><span>email:'.$email.'</span>'; 
 echo $html; 
?>
```

First I created the variable. And when doing so I insert the existing variables by escaping the php. Only once this final variable is created do I echo it.

Hope this helps you on your way.

Comment: Okay let me phrase it another way.

I have a contact.php which echo $name and $email.

I have another template.php that echo $html

$name and $email is within the $html

Comment: Have you tried updating your code to what I provided?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `include`. The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file, in this case - your template.

Answer (score 0):

Change the tags from `<php?  ?>` to `<?php  ?>` in your script

Answer (score 0):

Just Concatenation

```
<? 
$html = '<span>name:'.$name.'</span><span>email:'.$email.'</span>';
?>
```

Comment: Hi. It doesn't work. Do you do an include in my template php for the php then run this concat?

Comment: Do you use correct brackets `<? ... ?>` instead `<php? ?>` ?